# OpenVPN over UDP stopped working for some clients

Tags: openvpn, udp

I have a frustrating OpenVPN TLS error problem since a few days, where some clients can connect to my OpenVPN server and some cannot. It's running on Windows using UDP/1194 and all the clients have exact same settings. I am attaching a server log level 6 of a working client and one not working. I don't have access to the not working client log (it's remote).

In addition, this exact setup used to work for long time (more than a year) until it stopped three days ago.

It seems like the client can reach the server but the server cannot reply back to the client. BUT this only happens for some of the clients, even ones that belong to the same telco network (in remote areas). So I cannot imagine how it could be a firewall error.

Minimal server.conf

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca ...
cert ...
key ...
dh ...
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
```

Server log for client not connecting

```
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 LZO compression initialized
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'a8f55717'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '22188c5b'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 READ [14] from [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]bad_client:49003, sid=7ea5008f ee298f22
Fri Apr 07 09:51:38 2017 us=278366 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0

Fri Apr 07 09:51:40 2017 us=310517 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0

Fri Apr 07 09:51:44 2017 us=374822 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0

Fri Apr 07 09:51:52 2017 us=503448 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0

Fri Apr 07 09:52:08 2017 us=791909 bad_client:49003 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49003: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0

Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=87018 bad_client:49003 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=87018 bad_client:49003 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=87018 bad_client:49003 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting

Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 LZO compression initialized
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'a8f55717'
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '22188c5b'
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 UDPv4 READ [14] from [AF_INET]bad_client:49004: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]bad_client:49004, sid=3850de6b eadae20a
Fri Apr 07 09:52:39 2017 us=399300 bad_client:49004 UDPv4 WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49004: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:52:41 2017 us=775314 bad_client:49004 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49004: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:52:45 2017 us=292476 bad_client:49004 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]bad_client:49004: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
```

Server log for client connecting

```
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 LZO compression initialized
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'a8f55717'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '22188c5b'
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 UDPv4 READ [14] from [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]good_client:62320, sid=0a4a2388 525f8203
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=109968 good_client:62320 UDPv4 WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=156863 good_client:62320 UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=156863 good_client:62320 UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=156863 good_client:62320 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=156863 good_client:62320 UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Fri Apr 07 09:51:46 2017 us=156863 good_client:62320 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]good_client:62320: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
```

As you can see, the P_ACK_V1 that is sent back to the server by the second client, is never sent by the first client. So it tries to complete the handshake forever...

I realized this TLS error is a quite common issue, but with some of the clients working and some not? I have checked the server firewall and also some different configurations like the following, to no result.

local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (public server IP address)

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Could it be a networking/routing problem? Thanks so much for reading through!

Edit: Added client log for a connecting client. As expected, it matches the server log, acknowledging the packets. I don't have a log for a not-connecting client, since I could not replicate the issue with any client from my home network, and those ones are already remote...

```
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=228914 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=228914 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=228914 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491578005,WAIT,,,
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=228914 UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=229914 UDPv4 READ [0] from [undef]: DATA UNDEF len=-1
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=272916 UDPv4 READ [26] from [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=272916 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1491578005,AUTH,,,
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=272916 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194, sid=ba8f04dc 7b6b2ffb
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=273916 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=273916 UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=273916 UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=273916 UDPv4 WRITE [15] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=1
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=314919 UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=315919 UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=323919 UDPv4 READ [126] from [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Fri Apr 07 17:13:25 2017 us=324919 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]vpn_server:1194: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
```

Comment: What is in the logs on the client?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited to add the client log but only from one that works...

Comment: Well that probably isn't particularly useful, at least not without a failing log to compare it against.  A log from a failing client may have more error messages indicating why it is failing, that is what you should work on trying to get.

Comment: In case everything is the same and just some clients has trouble, try to lower MTU for the connection. I have face already temporary issues based just on topology of ISP changes (nothing visible, just sometimes working sometimes not). In case this is the issue (some part of transport is not able to transit "full packets" due to additional header) the lowering MTU could help as it will limit size of transmitting packets so it will not be impacted...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, this was neither a networking/firewall issue nor OpenVPN configuration. Just some of the clients (connected via prepaid 3G) did not have enough balance...

The twist is that the outgoing packets from the client could reach the server, but the incoming packets from the server could not reach the client. I guess the low balance limitation was only on downloading.